# How to put several renderText in a mainPanel?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm a beginner on R and Shiny and I have a little problem.

If you could help please, I would really appreciate.

For example, I've added the variable Group to the R data frame "mtcars" in characters format. Now I have 3 groups of cars : 1, 2 and 3, depending on the "mpg" level of each car.

I would like one renderText which shows the number of cars of the group(s) I have checked, a second one to show the number of 4cylinders cars of the checked group(s), a third one to show the number of 6cylinders cars, and a fourth one to show the number of 6cylinders cars.

If I keep only the Group textRender, it works great, but when I add the 3 others, there's an error and I don't find why.

This is the code :

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("Example"),
sidebarPanel(checkboxGroupInput("dynamic", "Groups", label = "Groups",
           choices = c("Group 1"="1","Group 2"="2","Group 3" = "3"))),

mainPanel(("Group : "), textOutput("textDisplay"),
        ("4 cylinders : "), textOutput("text4cyl"),
        ("6 cylinders : "), textOutput("text6cyl"),
        ("8 cylinders : "), textOutput("text8cyl"))))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$textDisplay <- renderText({
    a<-sum(mtcars$Group %in% input$dynamic)
  output$text4cyl <- renderText({
    b<-sum(mtcars$Group %in% input$dynamic) & mtcars$cyl ==4
  output$text6cyl <- renderText({
    c<-sum(mtcars$Group %in% input$dynamic) & mtcars$cyl ==6
  output$text8cyl <- renderText({
    d<-sum(mtcars$Group %in% input$dynamic) & mtcars$cyl ==8})})})})})
```

Thank you very very much for help, and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just created the groupings which are probably different than yours. This is one possible solution:

ui.R

```
    library(shiny)
    shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
            headerPanel("Example"),
            sidebarPanel(checkboxGroupInput("dynamic", label = "Groups",
                                            choices = list("Group 1"= "1","Group 2" = "2","Group 3" = "3"),
                                            selected = c(1,2,3))),

            mainPanel(("Group : "), textOutput("textDisplay"),
                      ("4 cylinders : "), textOutput("text4cyl"),
                      ("6 cylinders : "), textOutput("text6cyl"),
                      ("8 cylinders : "), textOutput("text8cyl"))))
```

server.R

```
    library(shiny)
    library(dplyr)

    group <- c(rep("1", 11), rep("2", 11), rep("3", 10))
    group
    mtcars$Group<-factor(group)

    shinyServer(function(input, output) {
            selection <- reactive({
                    filter(mtcars, Group %in% input$dynamic)
            })
            output$textDisplay <- renderText({
                    NROW(selection())
            })
            output$text4cyl <- renderText({
                    tmp <- selection()
                    NROW(filter(tmp, cyl == 4))
            })
            output$text6cyl <- renderText({
                    tmp <- selection()
                    NROW(filter(tmp, cyl == 6))
            })
            output$text8cyl <- renderText({
                    tmp <- selection()
                    NROW(filter(tmp, cyl == 8))
            })
            })
```

Comment: Hello Valter, it's so great, it's exactly what I was triyng to get ! Even if I didn't understand yet what was the problem, I'm very happy. Thank you very ver much. Have a nice day.

Comment: Please, just one more question Valter, how can I do to get all the checkboxes checked when I run the prog ? I tried with 'selected = "Group 1" "Group 2" "Group 3"' but I get an error message : ERROR: argument is not interpretable as logical. Thank you so much.

Comment: Valter, you're the King ! Thanks a lot Have a great day.